# Use $scope function on input type checkbox with ngClick or ngChecked to dispaly results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I want to show results on clicking checkbox items.
For that I tried with `ng-click` but it returns results only after it was unchecked rather on checked.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
    <div class="business-type">
           <div class="col-sm-12 filter-wrap-inner">
              <label for="rad1" ><input type="checkbox" name="reason-closing" value="Transporter" id="ad_Checkbox1" class="ads_Checkbox" ng-model="isTransporterSelected" ng-change="searchUser()"> Transporter</label>
           </div>
           <div class="col-sm-12 filter-wrap-inner">
              <label for="rad1" ><input type="checkbox" name="reason-closing" value="Broker"  id="ad_Checkbox1" class="ads_Checkbox" ng-model="isBrokerSelected" ng-change="searchUser()">Broker</label>
           </div>                      
           <div class="col-sm-12 filter-wrap-inner">
              <label for="rad1" ><input type="checkbox" name="reason-closing" value="Fleet Owner" id="ad_Checkbox1" class="ads_Checkbox" ng-model="isFleetownerSelected" ng-change="searchUser()">Fleet Owner</label>
           </div>
       </div>

JS:

$scope.isTransporterSelected = false;
$scope.isBrokerSelected = false;
$scope.isFleetownerSelected = false

$scope.searchUser = function(){
  $('.load-board-loader').show();
  var i;
  var containCount= 41;
  var vFromStateId = vToStateId = fromStateId = toStateId = '';
  var stateId=[];
  var $el=$("#usersearch-origin");
  $el.find('option:selected').each(function(){
      stateId.push({value:$(this).val(),text:$(this).text()});
  });

  var originId=[];
  var $el=$("#usersearch-source");
  $el.find('option:selected').each(function(){
      originId.push({value:$(this).val(),text:$(this).text()});
  });
  for(i=0;i<(stateId.length);i++)
  {
    if(i==0)
    {
      fromStateId = stateId[i].value;
    }
    else{
      fromStateId = fromStateId+','+stateId[i].value;
    }
  }

  for(i=0;i<(originId.length);i++)
  {
    if(i==0)
    {
      toStateId = originId[i].value;

    }
    else{
      toStateId = toStateId+','+originId[i].value;
    }
  }

  vFromStateId = fromStateId ; 
  vToStateId = toStateId ;
  var data ={
    fromStateIds: vFromStateId,
    toStateIds: vToStateId,
    typeOfBusiness: businessTypeValue,
    vehicleClassIds: truckTypeValue,
    orgName: '',
  }
  var url = 'url.com'; 
  //if(vFromStateId != '' || vToStateId != ''){
    $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST", //Use "PUT" for HTTP PUT methods
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success:function(response){
      if ($scope.isTransporterSelected || $scope.isBrokerSelected || $scope.isFleetownerSelected) {
        debugger
        $scope.users = response.directory;
        for(var j= 0; j<response.directory.length; j++){
        }
        $scope.$apply();
        $('.load-board-loader').hide();
      } else {
        $scope.users = response.directory;
        for(var j= 0; j<response.directory.length; j++){
        }
        $scope.$apply();
        $('.load-board-loader').hide();
      }

    },
    error: function(error){
      alert("Sorry , No data available"); 
    }
  });
```

I am updated my code with latest code as per comments below in this question.
Please let me know which part i need to change.
Any help over this will be very much helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind `ngModel` directive with checkbox then use `ngChange` which evaluates the given expression when the user changes the input value instead of `ngClick`

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.isTransporterSelected = false;
      $scope.searchUser = function() {
        //For debugging
        console.clear();

        if ($scope.isTransporterSelected) {
          console.log('Transporter selected search student')
        } else {
          console.log('Transporter deselected donot search student')
        }
      }
    }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Controller as nb">
    <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="isTransporterSelected" value="Transporter" ng-change="searchUser()" > Transporter</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: i tried with your code. might be i am doing some thing wrong . i am updating my code with latest change code. please have a look.

Comment: @TanmoySarkar use [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) instead `$.ajax`

Comment: can you please edit this. i am facing silly errors from my side